# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kumaGauge is not a function

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am using kuma-gauge.jquery.js to draw a gauge chart.

**The js code is:**

```
(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var config = {
        radius : 180,
        paddingX : 25,
        paddingY : 25,
        gaugeWidth : 25,

        fill : '0-#FE5249:5-#FA8B1B:10-#F8A903:30-#70CD60:50-#19C1E6:100-#19C1E6',
        gaugeBackground : '#f4f4f4',
        background : '#fff',

        showNeedle : true,
        showNeedles : true,
        animationSpeed : 700,

        width : 0,
        height : 0,
        centerX : 0,
        centerY : 0,

        min : 0,
        max : 1000,
        value : 80,
       
        valueLabel : {
            display : true,
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontColor : '#1ABFE9',
            fontSize : '95',
            fontWeight : 'normal',
                
        },
         valueLabel2 : {
            display : true,
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontColor : '#1ABFE9',
            fontSize : '20',
            fontWeight : 'normal',
             
        },
        title : {
            display : true,
            value : 'Avg',
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontColor : '#000',
            fontSize : '13',
            fontWeight : 'normal',
            centerX : 0,
            centerY : 0,
        },
         title2 : {
            display : true,
            value : 'You',
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontColor : '#000',
            fontSize : '13',
            fontWeight : 'normal',
            centerX : 0,
            centerY : 0,
        },
        label : {
            display : true,
            left : '300',
            right : '950',
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontColor : '#000',
            fontSize : '12',
            fontWeight : 'normal'
        }
    };

    // Create an arc with raphael.js
    Raphael.fn.arc = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, radius1, radius2, angle) {
        var arcSVG = [radius1, radius2, angle, 0, 1, endX, endY].join(' ');
        return this.path('M' + startX + ' ' + startY + ' a ' + arcSVG);
    };

    // Calculate a circular arc with raphael.js
    Raphael.fn.circularArc = function(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
        var startX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(startAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var startY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(startAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var endX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(endAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var endY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(endAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        return this.arc(startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY, radius, radius, 0);
    };

    // The kuma Gauge constructor
    function kumaGauge(element, options , method) {
        // This
        var _this = this;

        // The element
        _this.element = element;
        _this.$element = $(element);

        // The config
        _this.config = $.extend( {}, config, options );
        _this._config = config;

        _this.method = method;

        // The actual gauge
        _this.gauge = {};

        // Initialise
        _this.init();
    }

    // Extend the kumaGauge object
    kumaGauge.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            // this
            _this = this;

            if (!_this.method) {
                _this.draw();
            }
        },
        _setup : function() {
            // This
            _this = this;

            // Calculate some values needed do draw the gauge
            _this.config.width = (_this.config.radius * 2) + (_this.config.paddingX * 2);
            _this.config.height = _this.config.radius + (_this.config.paddingY * 2);
            _this.config.centerX = _this.config.paddingX + _this.config.radius;
            _this.config.centerY = _this.config.paddingY + _this.config.radius;

            // The div which acts as the canvas needs an id, so we give it a unique one if it doesn't have one
            if (typeof $(this).attr('id') === 'undefined' || $(this).attr('id') === '') {
                _this.config.id = 'gauge-' + $('*[id^="gauge-"]').length;
                _this.$element.attr('id', _this.config.id);
            }
        },
        _calculateRotation : function(min, max, val) {
            var _range, _rotation;
            _range = max - min;

            if (val < max && val > min) {
                _rotation = 180 * ((val - min) / _range);
            } else if (val <= min){
                _rotation = 0;
            } else {
                _rotation = 180;
            }

            return _rotation;
        },
        draw : function() {
            //this
            var _this = this;

            // Setup all the needed config variables
            _this._setup();

            // Make the base drawing Canvas
            _this.gauge = new Raphael(_this.config.id, _this.config.width, _this.config.height);

            // Draw the gauge
            _this.gauge.gauge = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                           _this.config.radius, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.gauge.attr({
                'fill' : _this.config.fill,
                'stroke' : 'none'
            });
            _this.gauge.gauge.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge');

            // Draw the gauge background
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                                     _this.config.radius, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.attr({
                'fill' : _this.config.gaugeBackground,
                'stroke' : 'none'
            });
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__background');

            // Draw the white center arc
            _this.gauge.centerArc = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                               _this.config.radius - _this.config.gaugeWidth, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.centerArc.attr({
                'fill' : _this.config.background,
                'stroke' : 'none'
            });
            _this.gauge.centerArc.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__center');

            // Draw the needle
      //      if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
      //          _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.paddingY - -10, 15, 15);
      //          _this.gauge.needle.attr({
      //              'fill' : '#fff',
      //              'stroke' : '#1ABFE9',
                     //'stroke-width' : '3',
      //          });
      //          _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle');
      //          _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle');
      //      }

            if (_this.config.showNeedles) {
                _this.gauge.needles = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -45, _this.config.paddingY - -19, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needles.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needles.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles4');
                _this.gauge.needles.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles4');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -167, _this.config.paddingY - -157, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles8');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles8');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -155, _this.config.paddingY - -120, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles7');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles7');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -129, _this.config.paddingY - -73, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles6');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles6');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -92, _this.config.paddingY - -38, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles5');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles5');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 7, _this.config.paddingY - -13, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles3');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles3');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 64, _this.config.paddingY - -25, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles2');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles2');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 115, _this.config.paddingY - -60, 23, 23);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#55E5DA',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needles1');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needles1');
            }


            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX- 167, _this.config.paddingY - -162, 18, 18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle1');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle1');
            }


            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 160  , _this.config.paddingY - -130, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle2');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle2');
            }

            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 135, _this.config.paddingY - -80, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle3');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle3');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 90, _this.config.paddingY - -40, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle4');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle4');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - 36, _this.config.paddingY - -16, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle5');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle5');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -20, _this.config.paddingY - -14, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle6');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle6');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -70, _this.config.paddingY - -28, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle7');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle7');
            }

            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -110, _this.config.paddingY - -54, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle7');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle7');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -145, _this.config.paddingY - -98, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle8');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle8');
            }
            if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                _this.gauge.needle = _this.gauge.circle(_this.config.centerX - -162, _this.config.paddingY - -142, 18,18);
                _this.gauge.needle.attr({
                    'fill': '#fff',
                    'stroke': '#1ABFE9',
                    'stroke-width': '3',
                });
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__needle9');
                _this.gauge.needle.node.setAttribute('id', 'gauge__needle9');
            }
            
             //Draw the needle

            // Draw the bottom mask to hide the rotated background arc
            _this.gauge.bottomMask = _this.gauge.rect(0, _this.config.centerY, _this.config.width, 40);
            _this.gauge.bottomMask.attr({
                'fill' : _this.config.background,
                'stroke' : 'none'
            });

            // Draw the text container for the value
            if (_this.config.valueLabel.display) {
                if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 50,
                                        Math.round((_this.config.max - _this.config.min) / 2));
                } else {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 10,
                                        _this.config.value);
                }
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.valueLabel.fontColor,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.valueLabel.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.valueLabel.fontColor,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.valueLabel.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__value');
            }
            // Draw the text container for the value
            if (_this.config.valueLabel2.display) {
                if (_this.config.showNeedles) {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel2 = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 10,
                                        _this.config.value2);
                } else {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel2 = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 10,
                                        _this.config.value2);
                }
                _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.valueLabel2.fontColor,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.valueLabel2.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.valueLabel2.fontColor,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.valueLabel2.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.valueLabel2.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__value2');
            }

            // Draw the title
            if (_this.config.title.display) {
                _this.gauge.title = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 200,
                                   _this.config.title.value);
                _this.gauge.title.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.title.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity' : 0,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.title.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.title.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.title.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.title.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__title');
            }
            
             // Draw the title
            if (_this.config.title2.display) {
                _this.gauge.title2 = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX - -100 , _this.config.centerY - 180,
                                   _this.config.title2.value);
                _this.gauge.title2.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.title2.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity' : 0,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.title2.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.title2.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.title2.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.title2.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__title2');
            }

            if (_this.config.label.display) {
                // Draw the left label
                _this.gauge.leftLabel = _this.gauge.text((_this.config.gaugeWidth / 2) + _this.config.paddingX,
                                   _this.config.centerY + 10, _this.config.label.left);
                _this.gauge.leftLabel.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.title.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity' : 0,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.label.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.label.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.label.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.leftLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__label--left');

                // Draw the right label
                _this.gauge.rightLabel = _this.gauge.text((_this.config.width - (_this.config.gaugeWidth / 2)) - _this.config.paddingX,
                                    _this.config.centerY + 10, _this.config.label.right);
                _this.gauge.rightLabel.attr({
                    'fill' : _this.config.title.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity' : 0,
                    'font-size' : _this.config.label.fontSize,
                    'font-family' : _this.config.label.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight' : _this.config.label.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.rightLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__label--right');
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (_this.config.valueLabel.display) {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr('y', _this.config.centerY - 50);
                }
                if (_this.config.valueLabel2.display) {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr('y', _this.config.centerY - 10);
                }
                if (_this.config.title.display) {
                    _this.gauge.title.attr({
                        'fill-opacity' : 1
                    });
                }
                if (_this.config.title2.display) {
                    _this.gauge.title2.attr({
                        'fill-opacity' : 1
                    });
                }
                if (_this.config.label.display) {
                    _this.gauge.leftLabel.attr({
                        'y' : _this.config.centerY + (_this.gauge.leftLabel.getBBox().height / 2),
                        'fill-opacity' : 1,
                    });
                    _this.gauge.rightLabel.attr({
                        'y' : _this.config.centerY + (_this.gauge.rightLabel.getBBox().height / 2),
                        'fill-opacity' : 1,
                    });
                }
            }, 1000);

            // Animate the gauge to the right value position
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.animate({transform:'r' +
                            _this._calculateRotation(_this.config.min, _this.config.max, _this.config.value) + ',' +
                            _this.config.centerX + ',' + _this.config.centerY}, _this.config.animationSpeed, '<>');

        },
        update: function (data) {
            //this
            var _this = this;

            var  updateGauge = function(min, max, value) {
                _this.config.min = min;
                _this.config.max = max;
                _this.config.value = value;

                // Update the rotation of the gauge
                _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.animate({transform:'r' +
                    _this._calculateRotation(min, max, value) + ',' +
                    _this.config.centerX + ',' + _this.config.centerY}, _this.config.animationSpeed, '<>');

                // Update the value label
                if (_this.config.valueLabel.display) {
                    if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr('text', value);
                    } else {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr('text', (max - min) / 2);
                    }
                }
                // Update the value label
                if (_this.config.valueLabel2.display) {
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr('text', 'EXCELLENT');
                    if (_this.config.showNeedles) {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr('text', 'GOOD');
                    } else {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr('text', 'BAD');
                    }
                }
                _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr('text', 'EXCELLENT');
            };

            if (typeof data.min !== 'undefined' && typeof data.max !== 'undefined' && typeof data.value !== 'undefined') {
                updateGauge(data.min, data.max, data.value);
            } else if (typeof data.value !== 'undefined') {
                updateGauge(_this.config.min, _this.config.max, data.value);
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.kumaGauge = function ( method, options ) {
        var _method = method,
            _arguments = arguments,
            _this = this;

        if (typeof _method !== 'string') {
            if (_arguments.length === 1 ) {
                options = _method;
                method = false;

                return this.each(function() {
                    if ( !$.data( this, 'kumaGauge' ) ) {
                        $.data( this, 'kumaGauge', new kumaGauge( this, options, method ) );
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            return this.each(function() {
                if (typeof $.data(this, 'kumaGauge')[method] === 'function') {
                    $.data(this, 'kumaGauge')[method](options);
                }
            });
        }


    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

In HTML file my code is like:

```
        <body>
        <div class="js-gauge js-gauge--1 gauge"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kuma-gauge.jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.js-gauge{display: block;
    margin: 200px auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;}

</style>
        <script>
            $('.js-gauge--1').kumaGauge({
              value : 1000,

            });</script></body>
```

when I run the HTML file, I see error in Console saying

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kumaGauge is not a function

Comment: Check the browser debugging network tab for any file errors (eg 404 on kuma-guage).  Also check that jquery isn't loaded multiple times (eg some frameworks add an automatic jquery just before the `</body>` which overwrites the one you've included.   Finally, check which version of jquery is needed - the website uses 2.1.1 in its examples.

Comment: I have checked the Network Tab, no issue related to kuma-gauge. Jquery is not loaded multiple times and jquey version is 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

While including file kuma-gauge.jquery.js in your project, rename it to kuma-gauge.js

```
"<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kuma-gauge.js"></script>"
```

Worked for me.